# jQuery tabs, jumping to top of page, how to stop?

Tags: jquery, tabs

I've read the other posts on this, but I'm still unable to get may page jumping to the top when a tab is clicked. Heres the HTML

```
<ul class="tabs-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1"><i class="icon-list-ul"></i> Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2"><i class="icon-map-marker"></i> Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tabs Content -->
<div class="tabs-container">
    <div class="tab-content" id="tab1">Stuff</div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="tab2">Stuff</div>
</div>
```

And here is the js...

```
(function() {

    var $tabsNav    = $('.tabs-nav'),
        $tabsNavLis = $tabsNav.children('li'),
        $tabContent = $('.tab-content');

    $tabsNav.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.next().children('.tab-content').stop(true,true).hide()
                                             .first().show();

        $this.children('li').first().addClass('active').stop(true,true).show();
    });

    $tabsNavLis.on('click', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.siblings().removeClass('active').end()
             .addClass('active');

        $this.parent().next().children('.tab-content').stop(true,true).hide()
                                                      .siblings( $this.find('a').attr('href') ).fadeIn();

        e.preventDefault();

    });

})();
```

Now I've tried adding

```
onclick="return false;"
```

to the tab href in the html, but that is doing nothing. Any help very much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its jumping to the top because of this `<a href="#tab1">`

try `<a href="javascript:void(0);"` and use another attribute to identify which div should be opened , you can add anyattribute starting with `data-` such as `data-id="#tab1`  then read that attribute ,

or you can just rethink how your HTML is setup,

if you really must keep things the way they are then you can try

```
 var $tabsNav    = $('.tabs-nav'),
        $tabsNavLis = $tabsNav.children('a'),  //this line changed
        $tabContent = $('.tab-content');
```

then:

```
 $tabsNavLis.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();   //now this is <a> click , not <li> click
        var $this = $(this).parent();
        $this.siblings().removeClass('active').end()
             .addClass('active');
        $this.parent().next().children('.tab-content').stop(true,true).hide()
                                                      .siblings( $this.find('a').attr('href') ).fadeIn();


    });
```

Comment: Hi, only just got to computer to get to respond. Thanks for adding this, I shall have a look at it and let you know! Thanks.